# what is problme in query caching with phpfastcache?

Tags: php, caching

I am trying to cache a query on a page using http://www.phpfastcache.com/.

I am getting no errors on the page ,i can run this code with simple array but can not run in this query, what is my code problem?

```
<?php
require_once("cache/phpfastcache.php");
$cache = phpFastCache();
$products = $cache->get("product_page");
if($products == null) {
    $products = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
    $products->execute();
    $cache->set("product_page",$products , 600);
}
while($obj = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
?>
<div><?php echo $obj->text; ?></div>
<?php echo timeTonow($obj->time);} ?>
```